# SPARQL get data from list

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to list pokemons. I am able to reach to a list(wd:Q106036966) from the Pokemon entity(Q864) on  Wikidata.

But I can't find the way to retrieve the data on that list.

At first I thought that maybe the data wasn't added, but if I search for Charmander(Q3178753), I am able to get to the list going upwards in the hierarchy.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: You should share the query you currently have, just so people can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: if you already open a page of a Pokemon, you should have seen that "part of" is the relation between Pokemon and a list: `select ?list ?listLabel ?pokemon ?pokemonLabel {
  ?list wdt:P31 wd:Q106036966 .
  ?pokemon wdt:P361 ?list
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: with subtypes of "list":`select ?list ?listLabel ?pokemon ?pokemonLabel {VALUES ?pokemon {wd:Q3178753}
  ?list wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q106036966 .
  ?pokemon wdt:P361 ?list
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you start at [Q3178753](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3178753) (Charmander), you can see that it is an instance of [Q25930490](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q25930490) (fire-type Pokémon) which is a subclass of [Q3966183](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3966183) (Pokémon species).

To list all Pokémon species you need to go backwards: Get all subclasses of Pokémon species and then all instances of these subclasses.
Translated into SPARQL this will read like

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel {
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3966183                                                                                     
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

If you want more than just the names of the Pokémons you can extend this query to get e.g. height, weight, Pokédex etc.